# Get folder using SPQuery

Tags: 2013

I am currently getting folder by using its name

```
                    SPList sourceLib = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Library Name");
                    SPListItemCollection folderItem = sourceLib.Folders;
                    foreach(SPListItem folder in folderItem) {
                        if (folder.Name.Contains("ClientFolderName")) {
                            //some operations
                        }
                    }
```

Now instead of getting like this and doing a foreach, I want to get just one folderitem (with folder name "clientFolderName") with using SPQuery. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SPQuery's Folder property like this:

```
SPFolder folder = list.RootFolder.SubFolders["ClientFolderName"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Folder = folder;
SPListItemCollection itemsCollection = list.GetItems(query);
```

Comment: As this is one of the top hits on google for "Get folder using SPQuery", the answer should also include how to get a folder using an SPQuery.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a CAML query. The following should be enough:

```
SPList sourceLib = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Library Name");
SPFolder folder = sourceLib.RootFolder.Folders["ClientFolderName"];
```

Comment: It would be needed eventually if you want to query some items based on some conditions.

Comment: should I need to pass the GUID in place of ClientFolderName?

Comment: @vignesg: the folder name is the key you want. `sourceLib.RootFolder.Folders` collection accepts only strings as index, no GUID at all.